# Using GNU Screen on Kali Linux displays not expected

Tags: bash, kali-linux, gnu-screen

[image: using screen on Kali linux]

When I used screen and splited vertically, right session cursor appeared the picture above. How can I fix this?

The procedure I took was

1. I typed `screen` on the left session which is bash terminal
2. I typed `crtl + a` + `|` for splitting session vertically
3. I typed `ctrl + a` + `tab` for moving cursor to the right
4. I typed `ctrl + a` + `ctrl + a` to start a session
5. I logged into Kali linux via ssh
6. I pressed enter multiple times which resulted like the picture above

Comment: If this screenshot is from a terminal window, we should know which one you are using.

Comment: @Philippos I was using bash terminal with macOS Montery

Answer (score 0):

[image: solved]

I've solved it!

key point was to ssh login to Kali linux first and then use GNU screen

procedure I took was

1. login via ssh from bash terminal to the host
2. type `screen` command in order to use GNU screen
3. type ``` ctrl + a``| ``` to vertically split the terminal
4. type ``` ctrl + a``shift + tab ``` to move the cursor
5. type ``` ctrl + a``c ``` to start a new window